# unity pauses on its own when ever an object hits another object with rigidbody and box collider

Tags: unity-game-engine, collider

This is the code below:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("groumd"))
    {
        DestroySelf();
    }
}

private void DestroySelf()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Comment: Is it pausing or stopping because there's an error?

Comment: I suspect what @RetiredNinja already said and you probably have `Pause On Error` enabled for the Console in Unity. I would further suspect a **typo** in your tag `groumd` which most probably should rather be `ground` .. Compare that throws an error if the tag is misspelled/does not exist for making your debug live a bit easier ;) Btw it's very questionable that you need a method just to call another one-liner ;) I would directly call `Destroy` instead of `DestroySelf` ;)

Comment: There's no error,once it collides it pauses

Comment: And I fixed the typo, still pausing. I have more codes for that method, thanks for the concern thou